# пайтон намертво зависает при попытках последовательного проигрывания музыки через discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Мой бот проигрывает музыку после команды "играй х(порядковый номер песни)"
Это работает.
Но когда я пытался сделать так, чтобы он проигрывал несколько песен подряд с помощью той же команды, но указывая несколько песен он зависает примерно через минуту после начала проигрывания первой песни.
В чём проблема?

Вот кусок кода

```
for i in range(len(a)-2):
vc.pause()                 vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe",source=music[int(a[i+1])-1]))
vc.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(vc.source)
vc.source.volume = vm
while vc.is_playing():
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Рекомендую использовать Lavalink вместе в wavelink py, будут всё куда [проще](https://github.com/PythonistaGuild/Wavelink)

Comment: простите, но что это такое?

Comment: Wavelink - это модуль для python и discord.py, который позволяет запускать музыку в дс без проблем, а lavalink - это нода для связи с wavelink. Вот [discord server wavelink](https://discord.com/invite/RAKc3HF)

Comment: Извините, но я хочу проигрывать музыку из фалов на пк

Answer (score 0):

**Гайд по установке wavelink для discord.py**

1. В консоли прописать **pip install wavelink**
2. Переходим на wavelink discord server https://discord.com/invite/RAKc3HF и скачиваем то, что указано на скриншоте.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Запускает файл **wavelinked.exe**, ждём загрузки файлов, они будут загружены в ту категорию, где сейчас находится исполняемый exe файл, заходим в неё.
4. Копируем файлы в папку с ботом. Скоро они нам пригодятся(application.yml, Lavalink.jar). Папку **lavalink** можно удалить.
5. Создаём новый ког для музыки.
6. Копируем код с гитхаба https://github.com/PythonistaGuild/Wavelink/blob/master/examples/advanced.py и вставляем его в новосозданный ког.
7. Заходим в файл **application.yml**, редактируем поля **port** и **address**. Вместо порта указываем любой открытый порт на пк, если же запуск происходит с удалённого сервера, то соответственно указываем порт удалённого сервера. С адресом точно так же, 127.0.0.1 это локальный сервер. Пароль менять на усмотрение, но я настоятельно рекомендую это сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

8. Установим java для запуска lavalink сервера. Для этого перейдём на сайт https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаем всё как на скриншотах, скачиваем, а затем устанавливаем java.
P.S. Чтобы проверить, установилась java или нет пропишем в консоли java -version.

9. Создадим батник для запуска lavalink. Создаём текстовый документ, переименовываем его в node.bat, изменяем и пишем:

```
@echo off
title Lavalink
java -jar Lavalink.jar
```

10. Заходим в новый ког, куда мы скопировали код из github, и изменяем данные в классе **Music** словаря **nodes**. host, port, rest_uri, password. Эти данные мы указывали ранее в файле **application.yml**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

11. Запускаем новосозданный батник, подключаем ког к боту, запускаем бота.
12. Вот и всё, после всех этих манипуляций музыка в боте должна заработать.